# How can I set my LCD as default LCD?

Tags: ubuntu, server, default, display, spi

I have an ARM-based board(http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_M1) and use Ubuntu-server 16.04 on it. I have a 2.2" TFT-LCD with SPI connection, and use this framebuffer driver(https://github.com/notro/fbtft) to launch it. I can setup my LCD with this command:

```
sudo modprobe fbtft_device custom name=fb_ili9341 gpios=reset:1,dc:201,led:6 speed=16000000 rotate=90 bgr=1
```

And before, when I had Ubuntu desktop, I could change display by this command:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb8 startx
```

But in Ubuntu-server I get this error message:

```
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic armv7l Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux nanopim1 3.4.113-sun8i #16 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 13 14:15:57 CEST 2017 armv7l
Kernel command line: root=UUID=10b3b795-f372-4ea9-b78a-93ae9355c20c rootwait rootfstype=ext4 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200 hdmi.audio=EDID:0 disp.screen0_output_mode=1920x1080p60 panic=10 consoleblank=0 loglevel=1 ubootpart=bd75a2d6-01 ubootsource=mmc   sunxi_ve_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_g2d_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_fb_mem_reserve=16 cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1
Build Date: 13 October 2017  01:59:44PM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Oct 26 16:44:04 2017
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

And have only a blank screen. I want to know how can I set this LCD as my boards default LCD and make it to run.

In addition I must say I have installed xorg and openbox too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this steps:

Add to file `/etc/modules-load.d/fbtft.conf`

```
spi-bcm2835

fbtft_device
```

Add to file `/etc/modprobe.d/fbtft.conf`

```
options fbtft_device custom name=fb_ili9341 gpios=reset:1,dc:201,led:6 speed=16000000 rotate=90 bgr=1
```

Add to `/etc/rc.local`

```
startx
```

And my SPI LCD works automatically at the system startup.